# Pesquisa valor em array PHP

Tags: php, array

Como eu posso pesquisar pelo valor da chave de "item_a" e retornar todos os valores da chave de "valor_a" no array abaixo? Exemplo: quero pesquisar pelo item_a = 3 e que seja retornado os valores 396, 1514 e 2106.

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'item_a' => string '3' (length=1)
      'valor_a' => string '396' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'item_a' => string '3' (length=1)
      'valor_a' => string '1514' (length=4)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'item_a' => string '3' (length=1)
      'valor_a' => string '2106' (length=4)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'item_a' => string '6' (length=1)
      'valor_a' => string '1020' (length=4)
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'item_a' => string '4' (length=1)
      'valor_a' => string '1319' (length=4)
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      'item_a' => string '11' (length=2)
      'valor_a' => string '1912' (length=4)
```

Comment: Basta percorrer o array principal, verificar se a chave existe e ir juntando os elementos num novo array.

Comment: Não use saudações nem cumprimentos, veja [que tipo de comportamento é esperado dos usuários?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo a logica você precisa de:

1 -  Array com os valores

```
$items = [
  ["item_a" =>3,"valor_a" =>396],
  ["item_a" =>3,"valor_a" =>1514],
  ["item_a" =>3,"valor_a" =>2106],
  ["item_a" =>6,"valor_a" =>1020],
  ["item_a" =>4,"valor_a" =>1319],
  ["item_a" =>11,"valor_a" =>1912]
];
```

2 -  rodar um ciclo para verificar em cada posição do array($items) dentro dele a posição item_a é igual a 3 , se sim você retira o valor e guarda em um outro array

```
foreach( $items as $key => $value ){
  if($value["item_a"] == 3){
     $b[] = $value["valor_a"];
  }
}
```

3 - Agora você precisa mostrar esses valores então você faz um novo ciclo no novo array

```
foreach( $b as $key => $value ){
  echo $value;
}
```

Código completo

```
<?php
$items = [
  ["item_a" =>3,"valor_a" =>396],
  ["item_a" =>3,"valor_a" =>1514],
  ["item_a" =>3,"valor_a" =>2106],
  ["item_a" =>6,"valor_a" =>1020],
  ["item_a" =>4,"valor_a" =>1319],
  ["item_a" =>11,"valor_a" =>1912]
];
$b = [];    
foreach( $items as $key => $value ){
  if($value["item_a"] == 3){
    $b[] = $value["valor_a"];
  }
}
foreach( $b as $key => $value ){
  echo $value;
}
?>
```

Comment: Não seria melhor já exibir na tela no primeiro foreach? if($value["item_a"] == 3) { echo $value['valor_a']; }

Comment: Se fizesse uma função para filtrar e retornando um novo array e outra para exibir seria o correto, porém como não se trata de função, não é necessário nem criar outro array. Imprimi direto! Mas funciona.

Answer (score -1):

Segue dois exemplos que podem te dar uma visão de como resolver o seu problema. Teste aqui
https://3v4l.org/uPRHp

```
<?php

$items = [
  ["item_a" =>3,"valor_a" =>396],
  ["item_a" =>3,"valor_a" =>1514],
  ["item_a" =>3,"valor_a" =>2106],
  ["item_a" =>6,"valor_a" =>1020],
  ["item_a" =>4,"valor_a" =>1319],
  ["item_a" =>11,"valor_a" =>1912]
];
$search = 3;
$newArray = array_filter($items, function($item) use($search) {
    return $item['item_a'] == $search;
});

print_r($newArray);

$newArray2 = array_map(function($item) use($search) {
    if ($item['item_a'] == $search) {
      return $item['valor_a'];
    }
},$items);


print_r(array_filter($newArray2));
```

Saída

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item_a] => 3
            [valor_a] => 396
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item_a] => 3
            [valor_a] => 1514
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [item_a] => 3
            [valor_a] => 2106
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => 396
    [1] => 1514
    [2] => 2106
)
```

Comment: Funcionou!! Tanks

Comment: Mas você conseguiu entender o que cada função faz?

Comment: Opa... consegui sim... a lógica tá legal pra entender!!